# Are all the endomorphisms of a group generated by a conjugation?

Tags: group-theory

It is well known that for a group $G$, the mapping from $G$ to $G $

$$  r \rightarrow s r s^{-1} $$

generated by an arbitrary element $s \in G $ is an endomorphism of $G$.

The question is then, are all the endomorphisms of $G$ generated in this way?

Answer (score 1):

No, take $G= ((0,\infty ) ,\cdot )$ and $f(t) = t^2 .$

Comment: ... or any non-trivial autodomorphism of an abelian group, e.g. $x\mapsto -x$